# How can I force a reindexing of a bad robots.txt page with Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search, robots.txt, google-search-console

### My problem

So I made a pretty big mistake recently with my `robots.txt` file. I added in a line to keep data files from being read with the intention of keeping blog data `.txt` files from being crawled:

```
Disallow: *.txt$
```

Looking back, what I should have done was include a directory first:

```
Disallow: /blog/posts/*.txt$
```

But, since I failed to do that, Google is now failing to crawl my `robots.txt` file.

I have now fixed the file but I can't get Google Search Console to reindex the file since it still thinks it's not allowed to do so.

### What I've Tried

- I have tried pulling up the `/robots.txt` file in GSC and manually reindexing but no dice. The only info it gives me is that this is "*not allowed by robots.txt*"
- I have tried removing the `robots.txt` file from the site, manually reindexing in GSC with the hopes that it would realize it was gone and reset or something. Still nothing though, still said the action was "*not allowed by robots.txt*"
- I have also tried using the *robots.txt tester tool* but as that only works with **URL-Prefix Properties** and this is a **Domain Property** it won't appear in the list of available sites to test. If somebody knows of a way I can use this tool regardless (or temporarily convert my property to a **URL-Prefix Property**) that could still be a solution.

### My Goal

I would really like somehow reset my `robots.txt` file in GSC's index. Any and all suggestions would be much appreciated.

*Hopefully I described the issue clearly enough. If you need more info or context, please let me know and I will be more than happy to update the post.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, thanks to Barry Hunter over at the [Google Search Console Forums](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/101906652?hl=en&msgid=101906652) I was able to figure this one out. I can't imagine that this is a problem that a lot of people will have, but just in case, here is the solution.

1. Go to Google Search Console and add a new **URL-Prefix Property** (unless you already have your property set as a **URL-Prefix Property** in which case skip to step 3)
2. Make two of these properties using the same domain as your **Domain Property**. One with "*http://*" and one with "*https://*". They will auto verify as you already have claimed ownership of the **Domain Property**.
3. Go to the [Google Search Console robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en) tester tool.
4. Select one of your URL-Prefix Properties and the last indexed version of the `robots.txt` document will open.
5. Edit the text to correct your mistake and hit submit. Then, follow the steps shown in the dialog box.
6. Reload the page and, if the change stuck, you're good to go. Repeat from Step 4 with your other property and then try to load the URL on GSC again.

Comment: This solution worked for me; however, there was some issue on googles end going from steps 3 -> 4. It would not let me select a URL prefixed property. I believe the solution for this is to go to Google Search Console, click the domain selection in the top left, click "add property" then add the prefixed url in "URL prefixed." Once this is working, try steps 3-4 again. If that doesn't work you can manually edit this URL to take you to the correct screen `https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool?hl=en&siteUrl=<YOUR SITE URL W/ HTTP(S)>`